# Is fullscreen AlertDialog an alternative for Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I use fullscreen AlertDialog instead of Fragment in a small project. It's seems to working good for now, but is it right to use like this? Can i use it a bigger project?

Comment: Only you can decide if it is right or wrong. Nobody will punish you for that. Use whatever and however you want.

Comment: It's depend, what is the purpose of your AlertDialog?

Comment: In this app, i use it for show some content https://imgur.com/a/0GNqEca (i used picasso for images(images are dummy :))) Content can change with bottom buttons...

Comment: @Mete no, you should use a standard fragment for this purpose. AlertDialog are used to show a message, an alert, and should stay above the window (like for advising the user that something happened)

Comment: Users will punish you or lack thereof... or if not them then Google you naughty one =)